# DocuSign ColdFusion REST API v2 INVALID_MULTI_PART_REQUEST Boundary terminator '--BOUNDARY--' was not found

Tags: rest, coldfusion, docusignapi

I am trying to do a simple request for signature using ColdFusion. I am basing my code on the samples provided, but keep getting this same error. I have tried using validated XML and JSON and get the same error. Here is my code:

```
<cfset envDef = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\'http://www.docusign.com/restapi\'>" & 
"<emailBlurb>This is a test</emailBlurb>" & 
"<emailSubject>API Call for adding signature request to document and sending</emailSubject>" & 
"<status>sent</status>" & 
"<documents>" &
"<document>" & 
"<documentId>1</documentId>" & 
"<name>test.txt</name>" & 
"</document>" & 
"</documents>" &
"<recipients>" & 
"<signers>" & 
"<signer>" & 
"<recipientId>1</recipientId>" & 
"<email>cjfennim@earthlink.net</email>" &   
"<name>Charles Fennimore</name>" & 
"<tabs>" & 
"<signHereTabs>" & 
"<signHere>" & 
"<xPosition>100</xPosition>" & 
"<yPosition>100</yPosition>" & 
"<documentId>1</documentId>" & 
"<pageNumber>4</pageNumber>" & 
"</signHere>" &
"</signHereTabs>" & 
"</tabs>" & 
"</signer>" & 
"</signers>" & 
"</recipients>" &  
"</envelopeDefinition>">

<cfset filePath = ExpandPath("../test.txt") />

<!--- read contents of document into the request stream --->
<cffile action="read" file="#filePath#" variable="fileStream" charset="utf-8">

<!--- build the multipart request body --->
<cfset requestBodyStart = "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" &
            "Content-Type: application/xml\r\n" &
            "Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n" &
            "\r\n" &
            envDef & "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" & 
            "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" &
            "Content-Disposition: file; filename='test.txt'; documentId=1; fileExtension='txt'\r\n" &
            "\r\n">

<cfset requestBodyEnd = "\r\n--BOUNDARY--\r\n\r\n">

<cfset requestBody = requestBodyStart & fileStream & requestBodyEnd>

<cfset requestBodyLength = LEN(requestBody)>

<cfhttp url="#theurl#" method="post" multipart="yes">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-DocuSign-Authentication" value="#dsAuthHeader#">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/xml">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Length" value="#requestBodyLength#">
<cfhttpparam type="body" value="#requestBody#">
</cfhttp>
```

This produces the following requestBody:

```
\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\nContent-Type: application/xml\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data\r\n\r\n<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\'http://www.docusign.com/restapi\'><emailBlurb>This comes from Blue</emailBlurb><emailSubject>API Call for adding signature request to document and sending</emailSubject><status>sent</status><documents><document><documentId>1</documentId><name>test.txt</name></document></documents><recipients><signers><signer><recipientId>1</recipientId><email>cjfennim@earthlink.net</email><name>Charles Fennimore</name><tabs><signHereTabs><signHere><xPosition>100</xPosition><yPosition>100</yPosition><documentId>1</documentId><pageNumber>4</pageNumber></signHere></signHereTabs></tabs></signer></signers></recipients></envelopeDefinition>\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Disposition: file; filename='test.txt'; documentId=1; fileExtension='txt'\r\n\r\nTest file\r\n--BOUNDARY--\r\n\r\n
```

The file, test.txt contains "Test file".

I am able to get envelope information using the same header information so I know that is not the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Using cfsavecontent to create the requestBody also did not work:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="requestBody">

--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Disposition: form-data
#envDef#

--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: file; filename='test.txt'; documentId=1
#fileStream#

--BOUNDARY--

</cfsavecontent>
```

And encoding in iso-8859-1 rather than utf-8 also did not work.

Comment: it might not be an accurate error, are you positive that the file bytes are being appended correctly in your fileStream object right before the ending boundary?  The walkthrough he's referring to is [here](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument)

Comment: You can see the requestBody that is being produced in my post and it looks like the file bytes are being appended correctly, after all, it's just a text file with the words "Test file" in it. Recently I also tried using cfsavecontent to create the requestBody rather than enter the \r\n but that did not work either.

Comment: In your cfsavecontent attempt did you include cfoutput tags around the ColdFusion variables?  `<cfoutput>#envDef#</cfoutput>` and `<cfoutput>#fileStream#</cfoutput>`

Comment: The cfoutput tags were around the cfsavecontent tags.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the single quote characters you have around the XML namespace value.  When I copied your XML definition into PHP and ran there (I don't have ColdFusion) it complained about improperly formatted xml.  I had to change the single quotes to double quotes.  Not sure if that's PHP specific but might be worth a try.

So basically, what happens if you change from

```
<cfset envDef = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\'http://www.docusign.com/restapi\'>" &
```

to this?

```
<cfset envDef = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" &
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not fix the problem, but thanks for trying!

Comment: Is there anyway for you to see the raw request output that you are creating here so that we can inspect it?

Comment: We are installing WireShark on our development server which should give us that information.

Comment: We were unsuccessful using WireShark since the transmission is encrypted (https). We were unable to get the document sent with the envelope, but we were able to "create" an envelope and then add a document to it and then change the status from "created" to "sent". This is a roundabout way to do it but it works.